# Can't upload job artifacts to S3 object storage, 413 request entity too large

Tags: image, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, nginx-ingress, object-storage

I am using Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline to build an image (2,080 GB), it's artifacts are saved in a S3 Object Storage. When trying to push the artifacts the Gitlab-runner throws following Error:

**ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator | 413 Request Entity Too Large | id=96757 responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large**

*Additional information:*

Gitlab is selfhosted and deployed in a kubernetes cluster.

- Gitlab v15.9.1
- Gitlab Workhorse v15.9.1
- Gitlab-Runner v15.4.2

After some research i made two changes:

i increased **Maximum artifacts size** in Gitlab at Instance-, Group- and Project-Level:
[configuration gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKMrA.png)

and

i changed the client_max_body_size of ingress-nginx

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  client-body-timeout: "600"
  client_max_body_size: "0"
  enable-vts-status: "false"
  proxy-body-size: "0"
  proxy-buffer-size: 128k
  proxy-read-timeout: "600"
  proxy-send-timeout: "600"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
```

I also opened a ticket to my s3 service provider and asked if they have a limit to their uploads but they told me it's unlimited.

The error message is still the same and my question is, does anyone know what is causing this?
Every little hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is returned by nginx, not MinIO. There is no limitation related to object size imposed by MinIO.

Answer (score 0):

> I also opened a ticket to my s3 service provider and asked if they have a limit to their uploads but they told me it's unlimited.

That would be the most likey issue, as [illustrated here for instance](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/backup-utility-fails-with-error-s3-error-413-request-entity-too-large/42858):

> For anyone that might have a similar problem in the future, the problem proved out to be minio not being able to handle files larger than 145M.
>
> The solution based on [`values-external-objectstorage.yaml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/master/examples/values-external-objectstorage.yaml) was to configure task-runner to use an external bucket.

```yaml
gitlab:
  task-runner:
    replicas: 1
    backups:
      objectStorage:
        backend: gcs
        config:
          gcpProject: 
          secret: 
          key:
```

Comment: So we're not sure where the 145M concern on MinIO is coming from - as per our [docs](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/checklists/thresholds.html) we support a max object size of 50TiB or 5TiB for non-multipart uploads.

Typically when we see this issue it's related to a proxy, load balancer, or similar network control component that in some way constraints or limits the upload process and arbitrarily cuts off the maximum object size.

Without knowing more about what issue the OP hit in 2020, we cannot reasonably address that claim. the 413 error itself is NGINX, not MinIO

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with a Minio server behind Nginx on EKS. Fixed it by adding the following annotation to my ingress definition:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64m`